# Unity3d Issue NGUI UITexture/Facebook www Profile Pic

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, ngui, guitexture

Having small issue here with Unity and NGUI. NGUI has UITexture as its main texture such as Unity has GUITexture.

I sent a request to facebook to get the users profile image which sends back a perfect url which if I put in the browser works fine.

My issue is taking that Texture2D (Facebook API does it as a Texture2D) and putting it on my UITexture. For some reason it just does not take it correctly. I keep getting a null value for it. I am also using Mobile Social as well from the asset store any help, helps.

Here is my snippet of code.

```
 private void UserDataLoaded(FB_Result result)
{
    SPFacebook.OnUserDataRequestCompleteAction -= UserDataLoaded;
    if (result.IsSucceeded)
    {
        Debug.Log("User Data Loaded!");
        IsUserInfoLoaded = true;

        string FBNametxt = SPFacebook.Instance.userInfo.Name;
        UILabel Name = GameObject.Find("FBName").GetComponent<UILabel>();
        Name.text = FBNametxt;

        Texture2D FBLoadTex = SPFacebook.Instance.userInfo.GetProfileImage(FB_ProfileImageSize.normal);
        FBGetProfile.GetComponent<UITexture>().mainTexture = FBLoadTex != null ? FBLoadTex : PlaceHolderImg;
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("User data load failed, something was wrong");
    }
}
```

The placeholder image is just a already selected image used if the fbprofile pic does is null. Which I keep getting.....

Comment: Anyone have a fix?? I have been stuck on this for almost a day now...

Comment: It's not realistically possible to use "ngui" these days; it has been deprecated for 4? years.  Simply use the built-in Unity.UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you're looking for `RawImage` which exist for this purpose

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html

> Since the Raw Image does not require a sprite texture, you can use it to display any texture available to the Unity player. For example, you might show an image downloaded from a URL using the WWW class or a texture from an object in a game.

Use Unity.UI and use that feature.

Comment: this helped me out really well. I went ahead and used the Raw Image. However I am running into another issue once the user is logged in already a previous time. They sign back in automatically and the fb pic shows a red question mark. About to make a topic for this I think cant figure out why..... :(

Comment: ok go ahead and ask a new question, try to be clear and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Add "Ngui Unity2d Sprite" component instead of UiTexture to your profile picture in editor and use below code in your Fb callback

```
 private void ProfilePicCallBack (FBResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null) {
            Debug.Log ("Problem with getting Profile Picture");

            return;
        }

 ProfileImage.GetComponent<UI2DSprite> ().sprite2D = Sprite.Create(result.Texture, new Rect(0,0,128,128), new Vector2(0,0));

}
```

there might be an another way to do this. but this worked for me